# Meaning and etymology of "twirling waxed mustaches"

Tags: etymology, idiom-meaning

Today, the New York Times online edition [reviews a documentary film.](https://nyti.ms/2Hh2ZR3) The review contains the following sentence:

> The filmmakers don’t villainize anyone, though a few participants come awfully close to **twirling waxed mustaches,** like an American manager who jokes to a Chinese colleague that it would be a good idea to duct-tape the mouths of talky American workers.

It's clearly nothing positive, but I have never heard of it, cannot deduce the exact meaning from context and could not find anything online, partly because most hits concern physical mustaches.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moustache_wax -- Such mustaches were a standard feature of villains in old dramas.

Comment: In the early 1900s, the villain stock character — the one who tied helpless lasses to railroad tracks — always a had long, thin, waxed mustache, and they’d constantly twist them (ostensibly, to maintain their shape, in meta-narrative, so you’d know they were *doing evil* and *enjoying* it). Google “Snidley Whiplash” to see this trope taken to the extreme for the sake of parody.

Comment: @HotLicks That would be a sufficient answer :-) (as would be Dan's comment).

Comment: it's the etymology that is difficult to pin down, not the trope.

Comment: @lbf The etymology of what? This isn’t a fixed phrase, it’s an ad-hoc description of salient characteristics of the trope. The trope *is* the “etymology” for the bolded language.

Comment: @DanBron when was it first so used?

Comment: @lbf As I said, this isn’t a fixed phrase. It itself doesn’t have a history. It’s like “green as a witch’s skin”. It’s pulling on cultural knowledge, an allusion, a reference, not a linguistic artifact.

Comment: so the OP should drop all ?'s as to etymology?

Comment: @lbf There isn’t an etymology to be had. Etymology applies to linguistic artifacts. This is a cultural allusion. You might as well ask “what is the etymology of the wizard of Oz”? (Not the words, the movie.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sense of 'twirling waxed mustaches':  [Dastardly Whiplash](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DastardlyWhiplash)

> An oddly specific kind of character, the Dastardly Whiplash is a
> cartoonish villain taken from the silent film tradition **[1891-1920]**. Usually a Man of Wealth and
> Taste, in Great Britain (*cough Evil Brit cough*), he was generally a
> Bad Baronet; in the U.S., he was often an Evil Banker who held the
> mortgage on the heroine's farm. Physically, he's slightly hunched with
> an exaggerated nose and chin, a curling black moustache (all the
> better to twirl at you, my dear)

and:  [JSTOR](https://daily.jstor.org/the-meaning-of-a-mustache/)

> At home, too, beards and mustaches reflected a kind of masculinity
> that was falling out of favor. In **1920**, Alma Whitaker, a Los Angeles
> Times columnist, complained that “tricky little mustaches” found on
> men returning from World War I

I appears from vaudeville to the the 'talkies' to the dashing soldiers of WWI returning, the twisting part came to connote 'evil design'.  My sense would place this figurative usage in AmE at the turn of the 20th C.

Comment: Turn of the 20th, no?

Comment: @DanBron i need more coffee